# Start request repeated too quickly on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: virtual-machine, ibm-cloud, systemd, ubuntu-16.04

IBM Bluemix is not showing logs of virtual machine on site with official ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine cloud image.

Logs:

```
mt-logstash-forwarder.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Stopped Multi-tenant Logstash Forwarder.
ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: mt-logstash-forwarder.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
ubuntu-16 systemd[1]: Failed to start Multi-tenant Logstash Forwarder.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bug of systemd 219 inubuntu 16.04. Upgrade to systemd 231 fixed this error.
Because of systemd 231 compiled for ubuntu 16.10 and stored in ubuntu yakkety repository you need to add this string

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety main
```

into file /etc/apt/sources.list and then run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --upgrade systemd
```

Answer (score 0):

I have installed redis-server by apt-get under ubuntu 16.04.

It works for me after:

1. apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install --upgrade systemd
3. Keep original redis.service systemd script.